# How to assign custom post template to its custom taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archive-template

I have created a custom post type 'interview' and also created custom taxonomy 'interview_category' for the interview custom post type, that custom taxonomy have terms like students, teachers, entrepreneur and some others.

I created a 'archive-interview' template for interview custom post type, what i need is the custom taxonomy terms of interview custom post type use the same template 'archive-template'.

i previously did this task but that time interview was a parent category of students, teachers etc. the code i used that time is

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'UseParentTemplate');

  function UseParentTemplate() {
   if (is_category()) {
    $catid = get_query_var('cat'); //current category id
    $category = get_category($catid);
    $parent = $category->category_parent; //immediate parent
    if ($parent){
        $parentCategory = get_category($parent);
        $parentName = $parentCategory->name;
        $parentid = get_cat_id( $parentName );
        if("85"==$parentid){
            if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $parentCategory->slug .    '.php') ) {
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-' . $parentCategory->slug . '.php');
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
 }
```

I work on custom post type first time please help me out from this, any help will be appreciated buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call your file taxonomy-interview_category.php to be automatically associated with your custom taxonomy.

If you want it to look like interview archive, you can just include archive-interview.php in your newly created taxonomy-interview_category.php.

I suggest you have a look at this image that explains WordPress template hierarchy and logic:

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg

Comment: thanks for reply bro i added this code in my function.php it work fine for me  function UsecustomTemplate() {
    if (is_tax( 'dastak_interview_category' )) {
       include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/archive-dastak_interview.php');
    } 
 }

Comment: The this is that such custom solutions like yours in functions.php will be a big pain in someone's butt once they have to change this behaviour, as they will be expecting exactly that template file to exist (or taxonomy-dastak_interview_category.php, if this is the real name of the taxonomy). Just have all this in mind, if you are going to sell or release freely this theme!

Comment: yes you are right bro that will be pain if i am going to sell.thanks for your suggestion i will keep that in mind too

Comment: Hey, it'd be great if you could mark the answer as a solution to your case :)